# No geometry passed when importing shapefile to database with ogr2ogr (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, ogr2ogr

I am trying to import a shapefile with the `ogr2ogr` command into my PostgreSQL database. Unfortunately it does import the attributes, but without the geometry.

This is my command:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=xxx user=xxx dbname=xxx password=xxx active_schema=agimos_gdm" -sql "SELECT id as komm, marktgebie as marktgebiet, netzbetrei as betr, betriebsst as betsta, name as name, segment as sgmnt_id, version_id as version_id, hydraulisc as hydrel from test_shapefile" test_shapefile.shp -t_srs EPSG:32633 -nln "gdm_usgmnt" GEOMETRY_NAME=geom --config PGSQL_OGR_FID usgmnt_id--config OGR_TRUNCATE YES --config CPL_DEBUG ON >log.txt  2>&1
```

logfile output

```
GDAL: Auto register C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll using GDALRegister_ECW_JP2ECW.
GDAL: Auto register C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_GEOR.dll using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll using GDALRegister_HDF5.
GDAL: Auto register C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\gdal_MrSID.dll using GDALRegister_MrSID.
GDAL: Auto register C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\ogr_OCI.dll using RegisterOGROCI.
GDAL: Auto register C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins\ogr_SOSI.dll using RegisterOGRSOSI.
Shape: DBF Codepage = UTF-8 for test_shapefile.shp
Shape: Treating as encoding 'UTF-8'.
GDAL: GDALOpen(test_shapefile.shp, this=00000213280EAE60) succeeds as ESRI Shapefile.
PG: Client encoding: 'UTF8'
PG: PostGIS schema: 'public'
PG: PostgreSQL version string : 'PostgreSQL 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-4.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit'
PG: PostGIS version string : '3.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1'
GDAL: GDALOpen(PG:host=10.16.0.59 user=agimos dbname=agimos password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX active_schema=agimos_gdm, this=000002132A5B8970) succeeds as PostgreSQL.
Warning 1: layer names ignored in combination with -sql.
PGCommon: Field sbls is of unknown format type bit varying (type=varbit).
GDALVectorTranslate: Skipping field 'geometry' not found in destination layer 'gdm_usgmnt'.
OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.597573 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.trgfnc_bi_gdm_usgmnt]  start processing ...  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.598254 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.network_getNemesysKey]  start processing Parameter: gdm_usgmnt  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.599038 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.network_getNemesysKey]  New nemesys_key: PI_00352993  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.599309 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.network_getNemesysKey]  end processing Time:  00:00:00.001026  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.599813 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_getMarktgebiet]  start processing ...  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.600318 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_getMarktgebiet]  Number of Marktgebiet: 0  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.600571 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_getMarktgebiet]  Kein Marktgebiet gefunden  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.600891 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.checkSegmentWithVersionID]  start processing ...  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.601478 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.checkSegmentWithVersionID]  end processing Time:  00:00:00.000589  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.602246 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.network_Edge2Topology]  start processing. Parameters are: 1028799 gdm_usgmnt  0  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.602351 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.network_Edge2Topology]  Constant SNAP RANGE used will be 0.01  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.602523 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.network_Edge2Topology]  Input Geometry is NULL. End processing Time:  00:00:00.000374  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.603107 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.inubit_api_createtimeseries]  start processing Parameter - inobjectname: gdm_usgmnt, innemesyskey: PI_00352993, geom:   <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.603421 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_get_DBName]  start processing Parameter:   <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.603894 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_get_DBName]  Current DB-Connetion  agimos  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.604060 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.inubit_api_createtimeseries]  DB-Name: agimos  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.604290 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_getMarktgebiet]  start processing ...  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.604458 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_getMarktgebiet]  Number of Marktgebiet: 0  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.604558 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_getMarktgebiet]  Kein Marktgebiet gefunden  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.605121 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.inubit_api_createtimeseries]  Request URL: http://10.16.0.52:8000/ibis/ws/nemesys_zrm_100_createGISTimeSeriesWebService  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:31.605226 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.inubit_api_createtimeseries]  Request Body: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:nem="http://10.150.42.15:8000/ibis/ws/1292427171867/nemesys_zrm_100_createGISTimeSeriesWebService"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><nem:createGISTimeSeries><nem:GIS-Typ>gdm_usgmnt</nem:GIS-Typ><nem:NemesysKey>PI_00352993</nem:NemesysKey><nem:Marktgebiet>Ost</nem:Marktgebiet></nem:createGISTimeSeries></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.503214 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.inubit_api_createtimeseries]  Response - Status: 200, Content <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><isns:Envelope xmlns:isns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsc="http://10.150.42.15:8000/ibis/ws/1292427171867/nemesys_zrm_100_createGISTimeSeriesWebService"><isns:Header /><isns:Body><wsc:createGISTimeSeriesResponse>Success</wsc:createGISTimeSeriesResponse></isns:Body></isns:Envelope>  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.503490 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.inubit_api_createtimeseries]  end processing Time:  00:00:03.900444  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.503960 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_length2d]  start processing, in geometry parameter is:   <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.504171 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_length2d]  Geometry type:   <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.504560 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_length2d]  Berechnete Länge der Inputgeometrie: , gerundet   <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.504693 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_length2d]  end processing Time:  00:00:00.000734  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.505142 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_length3d]  start processing, in geometry parameter is:   <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.505309 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_length3d]  A NULL-geometry was passed!  <NULL> - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.505498 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.util_length3d]  NULL geometry was passed. Passed geometry is NULL! A Geometry of type Linestring is expected.   NULLG - <NULL>

OGR_PG_NOTICE: NOTICE:  (Thu Jan 12 09:05:35.505657 2023 UTC) - [agimos_gdm.trgfnc_bi_gdm_usgmnt]  end processing Time:  00:00:03.90858  <NULL> - <NULL>

GDALVectorTranslate: 1 features written in layer 'gdm_usgmnt'
GenSQL: 1 features read on layer 'test_shapefile'.
Shape: 1 features read on layer 'test_shapefile'.
GDAL: GDALClose(test_shapefile.shp, this=00000213280EAE60)
GDAL: GDALClose(PG:host=10.16.0.59 user=agimos dbname=agimos password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX active_schema=agimos_gdm, this=000002132A5B8970)
GDAL: In GDALDestroy - unloading GDAL shared library.
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the geometry column to the selection

Comment: like: SELECT geometry as geom ? then i get "unknown field name geometry" in the logfile

Comment: whats the name of the geomfield in qgis?

Comment: Shapefile geometries are always called `the_geom`

Comment: unknown field name the_geom

Comment: if I use ogr_geometry instead it seems to work, but then I get "null geometry was passed" in the logfile

Comment: added my logfile output:

Comment: You append to an existing table that is created, probably due to an earlier error, without geometry. Drop that table and make a new start. The OGR SQL dialect that is used by default for shapefiles selects the geometry column automatically so the SQL statement is not the problem.